# How to get thumbnail of an image from it's web url in Android without full image download

Tags: android, image

I have list of urls relevant images loaded on to a server, i need to show thumbnail of these images in the `ListView` with out download of the image. 
Images will be downloaded on next screen when user go in details page.

Comment: No way, unless the server supports it with a separate thumbnail download URL.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Henry..

Answer (score 1):

Find out who manages the server. Contact that person. Ask them "hey, can you please give me alternative URLs for these that will return thumbnail images"? If you get the alternative URLs, use them with your favorite image-loading library to get the thumbnails.

Otherwise, it is impossible to get a thumbnail for an image that you do not have.

Comment: @CommonsWare some social applications such as WhatsApp or Telegram can make simple thumbnail before downloading image sir

Comment: @tux-world: They may *show* something that is thumbnail-sized. But then either they downloaded the full image (and are showing a small rendition of it), or they are downloading the thumbnail from a server. There simply is no other option.